# Accessing data within a Perl variable

Tags: perl

I dumped out a Perl variable called `$prefs` and got this:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'USERID' => 1286,
                 'PREFS' => {
                              '1' => {
                                       'VALUE' => 1,
                                       'OTHERS_POST' => 1,
                                       'CLIENTS_POST' => 1,
                                       'ASSIGNED_TASKS' => 1
                                     }
                            },
                 'dbh' => bless( {
                                   '_sth' => bless( {}, 'DBI::st' ),
                                   '_dbh' => bless( {}, 'DBI::db' )
                                 }, 'Taskman::DB' )
               }, 'USystems::UserPrefs' );
```

I'm pretty new to Perl, and I was wondering if someone can break down on whether or not it is possible to access specific data within this variable.

Like if I wanted to do an if statement such as

```
if (OTHERS_POST == 1) {
      // code }
```

How would I get to the actual `OTHERS_POST` inside the `$prefs` variable

Comment: The `USystems::UserPrefs` class is not one that I can find on CPAN, but I'd recommend trying the command `perldoc USystems::UserPrefs` to find any documentation on the class.  Alternatively you can follow Gingi's advice, do an end-run around the class and hope that it's implementation never ever changes...

Comment: You would get a proper answer if you showed the `USystems/UserPrefs.pm` module file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$prefs->{PREFS}->{1}->{OTHERS_POST};
```

Comment: note that this is bypassing the class's encapsulation; `$prefs` is a `USystems::UserPrefs` object; it would be preferable (pun intended) to use whatever method(s) that class provides

Comment: This answer is probably wrong, even though it will work, because `USystems::UserPrefs` may have an accessor method which exposes this data. (But there's no way for us to know, since it seems to be a proprietary module in your system.)

Comment: Yes, if a reference is a blessed object, a proper method should expose it in a more portable way. But this is not a CPAN question :) and for beginning Perl it shows how to access nested structures (at least nested hashes).